# Any (free) alternatives to MS powerpoint 2010 Exaltnow 1.5 plugin? (playing videos across slides with text)

Tags: plugins, video-editing, microsoft-powerpoint-2010

I need to play a video across multiple slides with text on top of it.

The problem is that I am the average consumer with-not-so-many money to spend and all those plugins cost like $150 u.s and even more.

Is there any free (or cheap, below $20) alternative to play videos across multiple slides?

or other software like powerpoint 2010 with that ability?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem  Why in the world would you ever want a video to span multiple slides?  In the worst case, splice the video!

Comment: with playing across multiple slides I mean it won't restart playing but continue playing when going to the next slide, just adding for clarity.. and there is no other solution to this problem than using a plugin, but I do not have that much money.

Comment: You want it to restart on every slide?  Or you mean it is restarting, and you want it to instead continue?

Comment: it restarts, and I want it to continue, and when I apply the "play" animation effect, I can't see any other text on top of it because mplay32 exe is running in front of the presentation, it's playing the video.. and the presentation is behind it when applying this effect

Comment: So, as I said, Why in the world would you want a single video to play across multiple slides?  In most cases, simply splice the video.

Comment: each slide is of unknown duration (like *some* presentations and I want the video to be an background, or well I will have to use 70  different videos with fade in-out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a single slide instead of multiples.
Add bookmarks to the video where you want your slide content to change (ie, a text box to appear, for example).  Assign a trigger animation to the text box and have it trigger on bookmark.